# Google Map (SupportMapFragment) Not Displaying marker in view pager fragments

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

Hello I have implemented `SupportMapFragment` for google map and trying to set my location button and marker on google map (`SupportMapFragment`) but it is not displaying but this code is working in Activity.

Please find the below code for more information.

```
public class MapsFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private static View view;
    private SupportMapFragment mMap;
    private static Double latitude, longitude;
    GoogleMap gMap;
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    public MapsFragment() {
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        latitude = 26.78;
        longitude = 72.56;
        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        mMap = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (mMap == null) {
            mMap = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, mMap).commit();
            mMap.getMapAsync(this);
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        gMap = map;

        gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new
                LatLng(49.39, -124.83), 20));
        gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(37.7750, 122.4183))
                .title("San Francisco")
                .snippet("Population: 776733"));
        gMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            requestPermission();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: take this as fragment activity instead of fragment.

Comment: yes map is showing Bajirao Shinde

Comment: i am working in viewpaser and appCompactActivity jay droider

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code from this

```
 if **(mMap != null)** {
            mMap = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, mMap).commit();
            mMap.getMapAsync(this);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

SupportMapFragment mMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();     
FragmentManager fm = fragment.getChildFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.map, mMapFragment).commit();
mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
mGoogleMap = googleMap;

if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // TODO: Consider calling
    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
    //                                          int[] grantResults)
    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
    return;
}
mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

buildGoogleApiClient();

mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .build();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // TODO: Consider calling
    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
    //                                          int[] grantResults)
    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
    return;
}
Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
        mGoogleApiClient);
if (mLastLocation != null) {
    //place marker at current position
    mGoogleMap.clear();
    //setLocation(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
}


mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
mLocationRequest.setInterval(50000); //50 seconds
mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(30000); //30 seconds
mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
//mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0.1F); //1/10 meter

 LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
Toast.makeText(customAdapter.getContext(), "onConnectionSuspended", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
Toast.makeText(customAdapter.getContext(), "onConnectionFailed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
sourceLat = location.getLatitude();
sourceLng = location.getLongitude();
getRestaurantDetails();
latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
//latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
//Log.wtf("Lat lng", lat + " " + lng);
mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 18));
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
}
```

where fragment is instance of your viewPagerFragment

in xml

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="250dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 public void drawMarker(double lat,double lon)
{
    if (mMap != null) {
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lon)).title(" Maps Tutorial").snippet("Android Ruler");
        marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
// Moving Camera to a Location with animation
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).zoom(12).build();
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        mMap.addMarker(marker);
    }
}
```

Refer here for detail:- http://coderzpassion.com/android-google-maps-v2-tutorial-with-markers/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't yet have the permission when you're using `setMyLocation();`. Try this -

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
        FragmentCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                PERMISSION_REQUEST);
}
```

The handle the result -

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST && grantResults.length > 0) {
        if (permissions[0].equals(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                //Calling the function here
                gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(context, "You need to provide " +
                        "permission to find the location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with viewpager and I solved it using **OnMapLoaded** callback. Try doing this

```
public class MapsFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, 
                                             GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback {

       @Override
       public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
            gMap = map;
            gMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(this);
       }

       //map loaded callback
       @Override
       public void onMapLoaded() {
           // add your marker now
           gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(37.7750, 122.4183))
                .title("San Francisco")
                .snippet("Population: 776733"));
       }
}
```